# Azure DevOps - Deployment problems

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, azure-functions, devops

I am trying to deploy a new code in an existing function on Azure but for some reason I am getting a Green/Pass pipeline but when I request the URL I got error 404.

What I have done:

1. Setup the function manually
2. Run a Pipeline with the stages:

   a) mvn package

   b) zip content of azure functions in the target

   c) Deploy artifact from agent to the pipeline

   d) Deploy artifact into a function using snipped code from microsoft.

The pipeline gets a green state and the function has been deployed:

```
Starting: AzureFunctionApp
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure Functions
Description  : Update a function app with .NET, Python, JavaScript, PowerShell, Java based web applications
Version      : 1.195.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azurefunctiontroubleshooting
==============================================================================
Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'test'
Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1639741028399.zip?***"}
Updated App Service Application settings.
Updated WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE Application setting to https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1639743928399.zip?***
Syncing triggers for function app
Sync triggers for function app completed successfully
Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight :test
App Service Application URL: http://test.azurewebsites.net
Finishing: AzureFunctionApp
```

but when I request the URL it fails, also I check the functions section in the portal , and the function that was there (deployed manually) got removed.

Note:
The code is fine because I can deploy manually the same code and it is working fine, via pipeline is not working.

**Pipeline code:**

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  serviceName: test
  jdkVersion: "1.11"

stages:
  - stage:
    displayName: Build
    jobs:
      - job: "Deployment_draft"
        steps:
          - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
            displayName: "Maven Authenticate"
            inputs:
              artifactsFeeds: test-artifactory
          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{ variables.serviceName }}/target/azure-functions/${{ variables.serviceName }}
              includeRootFolder: true
              archiveType: 'zip'
              archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              replaceExistingArchive: true
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              ArtifactName: '${{ variables.serviceName }}'
              publishLocation: 'Container'
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'SubscriptionTest(Subscription ID)'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: 'test'
              deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
              package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Comment: Hi user3658886; I'm not quite clear about your situation. When you say "Setup the function manually", do you mean that you deploy just the bare [function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.Web/sites?tabs=bicep)? Or that you are deploying a function app *and one or more existing functions to it*, before running the pipeline?

Comment: I mean, go to the Portal and create the function manually there without using any pipeline or script.


My problem is when I am trying to update an existing function using the pipelines

Answer (score 0):

**rootFolderorFile** - Enter the root folder or file path to add to the archive. If a folder, everything under the folder will be added to the resulting archive. Default value: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)

I have slightly modified your pipeline.

```
 pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
    serviceName: test
    jdkVersion: "1.11"

stages:
- stage:
    displayName: Build
jobs:
    - job: "Deployment_draft"

steps:
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
    displayName: "Maven Authenticate"
inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: test-artifactory


- stage : deploy
    jobs:
    - job:
    displayName : Function App update
    
steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: true
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    ArtifactName: '${{ variables.serviceName }}'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
    inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'SubscriptionTest(Subscription ID)'
        appType: 'functionAppLinux'
        appName: 'test'
        deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Refer  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml%2Ccsharp)

Comment: Hi Delliganeshs-MT; could you explain the significance of the rootFolderOrFile change?